# Variable assignment in conditional statement to test if property undefined in object

Tags: javascript

I wonder if it's a good idea to assign a variable inside a conditional statement.

For instance:

```
var sum = {}

var objs = [{"a": 1, "b":2, "c":3}, {"a": 2, "b": 3, "c":4}, {"a": 3, "b":4, "c":5}];

objs.forEach(function(obj) {
   Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
       ((sum[key] += obj[key]) || (sum[key] = obj[key]))
   });
});
```

or is it better to do something like:

```
objs.forEach(function(obj) {
   Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
       sum[key] = typeof sum[key] != "undefined" ? sum[key] + obj[key] : obj[key];
   });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a default value and add the actual value. Then assign to the object.

```
sum[key] = (sum[key] || 0) + obj[key];
```